# How to define an HList type, but based on another HList type

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have a case class:

```
case class Foo(num: Int, str: String, bool: Boolean)
```

Now I also have a simple wrapper:

```
sealed trait Wrapper[T]
case class Wrapped[T](value: T) extends Wrapper[T]
```

(and some other implementations of Wrapper that aren't important here)

I can use Generic[Foo] to get an Aux that represents this case class:
`val genFoo = Generic[Foo]`
(in my real code I use LabelledGeneric so as not to lose the field names)

This provides me with a type representing the *definition* of an HList:

```
Generic.Aux[Foo, Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil]
```

(when used with LabelledGeneric the definition is much more complex, but the same in essence)

Now I want to create a type definition for an HList that, instead of the raw types, includes the wrapped types instead.  Example:

```
type WrappedHlist = Wrapper[Int] :: Wrapper[String] :: Wrapper[Boolean] :: HNil
```

I can then use this type definition to, for example, generate a Circe encoder/decoder (I've provided the necessary Encoder/Decoder for the Wrapper type).

All the necessary information exists at compile time, as the definition of the second HList is easily determined from the first.  Right now, I can achieve this by writing out the definition manually, or by repeating the definition of the case class Foo with a redundant version where everything is defined as Wrappers.  How can I create a definition that doesn't require me to repeat everything?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is doable with a little bit of type classes, path-dependent types and Aux pattern:

```
trait WrapperHelper[In] {
  type Out
  def wrap(i: In): Out
}
object WrapperHelper {
  type Aux[I, O] = WrapperHelper[I] { type Out = O }

  implicit val nilWH: WrapperHelper.Aux[HNil, HNil] = new WrapperHelper[HNil] {
    type Out = HNil
    def wrap(i: HNil): HNil = i
  }

  implicit def hconsWH[H, TI <: HList, TO <: HList](
    implicit
    tailWH: WrapperHelper.Aux[TI, TO]
  ): WrapperHelper.Aux[H :: TI, Wrapper[H] :: TO] = new WrapperHelper[H :: TI] {
    type Out = Wrapper[H] :: TO
    def wrap(i: H :: TI): Wrapper[H] :: TO = i match {
      case head :: tail => Wrapped(head) :: tailWH.wrap(tail)
    }
  }
}

def wrap[I](i: I)(implicit wh: WrapperHelper[I]): wh.Out = wh.wrap(i)
```

HNIl is treated as a special case where In = Out. For everything else... you still have to map the type recursively. While not pretty this should do what you want:

```
@ wrap(Generic[Foo].to(Foo(1, "", true)))
res7: Wrapper[Int] :: Wrapper[String] :: Wrapper[Boolean] :: HNil = Wrapped(1) :: Wrapped("") :: Wrapped(true) :: HNil
```

Assuming that you want to provide some custom encoding/decoding logic you should modify the signature

```
implicit def hconsWH[H, TI <: HList, TO <: HList](
  implicit
  tailWH: WrapperHelper.Aux[TI, TO]
): WrapperHelper.Aux[H :: TI, Wrapper[H] :: TO]
```

to something like

```
implicit def hconsWH[H, TI <: HList, TO <: HList](
  implicit
  thatThingINeedToLiftAToWrapperA: Encoder[A], // whatever is needed to lift A => Wrapper[A]
  tailWH: WrapperHelper.Aux[TI, TO]
): WrapperHelper.Aux[H :: TI, Wrapper[H] :: TO]
```

Even if you don't need the implementation it is still useful to define typeclass here, just to provide some implicit evidence that would resolve the type for you.

Answer (score 1):

HList `Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil` can be easily transformed into HList `Wrapper[Int] :: Wrapper[String] :: Wrapper[Boolean] :: HNil` using standard type class [`shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapped`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L56-L86)

```
implicitly[Mapped.Aux[Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil, 
  Wrapper, 
  Wrapper[Int] :: Wrapper[String] :: Wrapper[Boolean] :: HNil]] // compiles
```